# Stitch multiple PDF's together

Tags: windows-7, pdf, pdfcreator

I am looking to stitch together multiple PDF's together into one file.  Is there a program/way (open source prefered) that can do this for me with little hassle?  If you share a program please give reasons why it will work and not just a link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I quite like [PDFSam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) as it's a nice cross-platform tool for splitting and merging pages from pdf files.

I believe it is written in Java (hence cross platform) and the source code is available.

I've used it as my fallback many times when people have scanned me a bunch of documents off the network printer that I've then had to split off and remerge in different orders and I'd have to say it has rather a lot of useful features for a tool whose only real purpose is to split and merge pdfs.

It even supports in-place reordering and thumbnail views which can save a bit of time, especially when you can't remember which file is which.

Comment: Installing PDFSam installs PDFSoda which I didn't want, didn't download and have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 9):

[pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) seems to be the most-often referenced tool for all sorts of PDF manipulation.

The sample command from their website describing how to merge multiple PDFs.

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf
```

A rudimentary GUI is available: [pdftk4all](http://pdftk4all.sourceforge.net/)

A slightly better looking one: [pdftk Builder](http://angusj.com/pdftkb/#pdftkbuilder)

Finally, [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/combine-documents) can merge documents as well, but it seems to be a bit cumbersome to do.  It'd be really handy for merging several different types of source files though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [gsview](http://ktmatu.com/info/merge-pdf-files/)

> Install GSview to the computer.
>   Convert file1.pdf and file2.pdf into
>   PostScript (.ps) format. In Adobe
>   Acrobat Reader this can be done with
>   File -> Open.. file1.pdf, File ->
>   Print... -> Select some PostScript
>   printer -> mark Print to file -> OK.
>   Write file1.ps to File name: -> OK.
>
> Repeat these steps to convert
>   file2.pdf into file2.ps. In this
>   example it is assumed that the files
>   are saved into c:\tilap\ directory.
>
> It's not necessary to have a
>   PostScript printer. A driver for it
>   can be installed even if there is
>   already some other printer attached to
>   the computer.
>
> Open Notepad (or some other text
>   editor), copy and paste the following
>   PostScript code snippet into an
>   editor. Edit the code to correspond
>   the directory where file1.ps and
>   file2.ps were saved. Remember to to
>   use \ instead of \ in path names.
>   Save the results to some directory as
>   file12.ps.

```
%!PS
% Written by Helge Blischke, see
% http://groups.google.com/groups?ic=1&selm=3964A684.49D%40srz-berlin.de
%
% The following 2 procs encapsulate the jobs to be processed
% much as is done with EPS images:
/_begin_job_
{
        /tweak_save save def
        /tweak_dc countdictstack def
        /tweak_oc count 1 sub def
        userdict begin
}bind def

/_end_job_
{
        count tweak_oc sub{pop}repeat
        countdictstack tweak_dc sub{end}repeat
        tweak_save restore
}bind def

% Now, add your jobs like this:
_begin_job_
(c:\\tilap\\file1.ps)run
_end_job_

_begin_job_
(c:\\tilap\\file2.ps)run
_end_job_

% and so on.
```

> Start GSview to view merged PostScript files. File -> Open... -> file12.ps.
>   ...and convert it back to PDF: File -> Convert... -> Device: pdfwrite -> OK -> file12.pdf

---

Other alternatives include [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) & [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

Comment: Does CutePDF stitch together PDF's?  I thought it only "saved" docs to PDF's?

Comment: should be able print multiple docs into a single PDF, haven't tried myself, though. @kron

Comment: You don't need to use gsview. gs itself can do the trick, with no ps in the intermediate. Just a single line: `gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

The Python command line program [`pdfly`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfly/) can do that:

- **Installation**: `pip install pdfly` and [more](https://pdfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html)
- **Usage**: `pdfly cat in1.pdf in2.pdf -o out.pdf` and [more](https://pdfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/subcommand-cat.html)

Please note that you need to have Python and the Python package manager (pip).